# In Altium Designer, use only part of an harness

Tags: altium

I would like to create harnesses with only some signals used, not all of them. for example:[image: Altium SPI Harness]

However, even with this harness definition:
  `SPI=SDO,SDI,SCK,SS0,SS1`,
I still get an error: `Conflicting Harness Definition for SPI`

Can I get the harness in the image to work? How should I configure Altium to do that?

Comment: You can put all the signals in the harness connector, but not connect to all of them.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, I did that to continue my project, but it looks ugly...

Comment: @ThePhoton  That can get unwieldy if you've got the SPI bus with lots of slave select lines.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, maybe route the SS lines as a bus instead of in a harness.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Fun tip: you can have a bus as a member of a harness.  However, I would want meaningful names for SS lines, if it can be helped.  `SS_EEPROM#` and `SS_RTC#` instead of `SS0#` and `SS1#`.

Comment: Look for the section "Connector-Free Signal Harness" [here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/((Creating+Connectivity))_AD#!CreatingConnectivity-WorkingwithSignalHarnesses).

Comment: @ThePhoton Would you mind changing your comment to an answer before it gets lost? The question is old, but I guess someone might still search for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name ALL signals of the harness in each and every instance of the harness. If you do not need a signal in one scheet just do not connect it to a net.